# Util class in Kotlin (Best Approach)?

Tags: kotlin

I was playing with `Kotlin`, and creating Util class with different ways. I am approaching a way that **works best** for calling by **either Kotlin or Java**.

Now I have created **many types** of **Util**. And now I am very confused which is **best to use** and most important **why**? I am finding **best way** considering **Heap, Memory, Performance**.

My question may look stupid for you guys, but I am in maze and can't come to a solution myself.

Here is my playground.

**I have created 5 Kotlin files**. in which I have put **foo()** method. and tried to call by Kotlin and Java.

> Calling class **Bar.kt**

```
class Bar {
    fun bazz() {
        UtilClass.instance.foo()
        UtilClassObject.UtilClassObject.foo()
        UtilCompanionObject.foo()
        UtilFileObject.foo()
        foo() // from UtilFile
    }
}
```

> Calling class **Qux.java**

```
public class Qux {
    public void bazz() {
        UtilClass.Companion.getInstance().foo();
        UtilClassObject.UtilClassObject.INSTANCE.foo();
        UtilFileKt.foo();
        UtilFileObject.INSTANCE.foo();
        UtilCompanionObject.Companion.foo();
    }
}
```

And here is the [maze](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/88VEGNoIxj8/maxresdefault.jpg) that makes me confused to choose best.

**UtilClass.kt**

```
class UtilClass {
    fun foo() { ... }

    companion object {
        val instance = UtilClass()
    }
}
```

**UtilClassObject.kt**

```
class UtilClassObject {
    object UtilClassObject {
        fun foo() { ... }
    }
}
```

**UtilCompanionObject.kt**

```
class UtilCompanionObject {
    companion object {
        fun foo() { ... }
    }
}
```

**UtilFile.kt**

```
fun foo(){ ... }
```

**UtilFileObject.kt**

```
object UtilFileObject {
    fun foo() { ... }
}
```

It may take to answer my question and explaining it well. So I really appreciate your efforts in advance.

Comment: Can you show how you prefer to call it instead of given all permutations that are possible, and the error you are receiving for that method?

Comment: I am basically Java developer, so I used to call like `Util.getInstance().foo()` or sometimes `Util.foo()` with static methods. and now I just want to know best of these. I am curious to know what are the difference in all above types, what is best considering heap memory.

Comment: @JaysonMinard Yes I found it most easy to make global methods like I mentioned in `UtilFile.kt`. But is that good practice to put 1000's of methods globally?

Comment: The method answered below would be the common way to do this for Java/Kotlin to have the same way to call a static/companion method.

Comment: @Khemraj It's extremely unlikely that the performance of your application is going to depend in any measurable way on how you declare your utility methods. If any performance difference between the different declarations remains after the JIT runs, it will be measured in nanoseconds. The difference which you can gain by choosing your algorithms and data structures correctly, on the other hand, is measured in milliseconds and seconds.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

All options are present on the Kotlin reference page for interop between Kotlin and Java:  https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html

Your options to call from Java something on class `MyUtil` and call it without an instance such as `MyUtil.foo()` then you would simply do one of the two options:

```kotlin
// smallest byte code, 
//   static invocation of foo() from Kotlin side,
//   also static call from Java to foo()
object MyUtil {
    @JvmStatic fun foo() { ... }
}
```

or

```kotlin
// creates two classes,
//    static lookup of companion followed by virtual call on that instance to foo() from Kotlin, 
//    Java is a static call to foo()
class MyUtil {
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic fun foo() { ... }
    }
}
```

And you would call it the same from Kotlin `MyUtil.foo()`.  This is specifically the model of making a [Kotlin method static](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#static-methods).

Both examples look the same from Java in that they are just direct static calls to a static method.  From Kotlin the first example is a static call as well, the second looks up an instance of the companion first and then does a virtual call on the method.  The Second example creates two classes, the other only creates a single class.

The other options you present are not more efficient and are uglier syntax.  Based on smallest byte code, fewest classes, and fastest performance pick the first example that is 1 class only and all static calls.

Comment: Okay, so this way would provide same calling way for both Java and Kotlin, and best according to you. But still I don't know why not global object without making class which gives shortest way to import?

Comment: You are now asking for opinions, which usually make bad questions because they don't end, cause arguments and aren't really useful.  The above sample is the idiomatic way to call a utility method on a class from both Java and Kotlin.  Anything else is not doing that but is doing something different than what is requested.  No matter what, you are importing something.  Either the class or the file as a class (top-level function).  Do you prefer knowing the hidden class name of the file?  or knowing the obvious class name of the class?  Choose.

Comment: "But still I don't know why not global object" -- you are using non standard vocabulary so I'm not sure what you are talking about.   I'll give you a second alternative in case this is what you are asking about, and update my answer.

Comment: updated answer for two equivalent answers, and neither is better than the other based on what is asked about here.

Comment: Sir I agree with your answer, but I am not asking about opinions, I wanted know difference in implementation and flow at run time among them, so I can choose one for all my future projects. I am assuring that the way I am choosing is best approach for performance. Syntax actually does not matter, performance does.

Comment: first choice above is 1 class instead of 2, less work from Kotlin side for the call, same from the Java side.  See the comments I added above them.

Comment: You can use the Kotlin ByteCode viewer to see the difference within your IDE.

Comment: I did not get `1 class instead of 2`, Which of your method creates two classes?

Comment: The 1 class option is the one you want.

Comment: Many thanks sir, you make me clear. I'll follow 1st way from now. Bytecode viewer is also helpful.

Comment: I've updated the answer based on your comments and clarifications.

Comment: @JaysonMinard The actually recommended approach in Kotlin is to do neither of what you've suggested, and to use a top-level function instead. This has no overhead, is the easiest to use from Kotlin, and requires the least code.

Comment: @JaysonMinard the first example generate a single class but an instance of the `MyUtil` object is created even though the method `foo` is static at bytecode level. So there is a (very) small memory overhead over a pure top level function.

Comment: @pdegand59 one instance of a class is not worth optimizing over, the existence of a 2nd class is more important for Android because of max count of classes/methods or whatever it does.  A top-level function done in a bunch of different files is going to create a bunch of classes that people might not be aware of instead of creating intentional classes themselves.